# og_members block & og_nodes block won't display content

Tags: 7, organic-groups

OG Version: 7.x-1.x-dev

My problem is that I can't get the og_members block & og_nodes block to show up under a group page.

Breakdown of my process:

- A fresh install of D7, necessary modules
- Created a new Content Type: Country: Specified as "Group type", "Not a group content type".
- Add a new country: "England".
- Createt a new Content Type: News: Specified as "Not a group type", "Group content type".
- Add a News, title "Hello World", select England in "Group audience".
- In Views page, I add block display for og_members, og_nodes. (All use default setting, no modification to the Views)
- Assign og_members block, og_nodes block to sidebar left. (Bartik)
- I go to "England" page, og_members block not show up, og_nodes block shows me "There is no content in this group."

I am pretty sure that the views setup correctly, as I pass the gid into the live preview, it does show the result. (See screent shot)

But the block just can't show up in a group page. I am guessing in the page, gid not passed to the block or what?

Am I missing any steps?

Thanks in advanced!!

**Update:** I found the solution by enabling the OG context module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

og_nodes and og_members did not exist prior to views 3 beta 3's release.  The user must have been using a dev version at this time because I was unable to reproduce this until views beta 3 came out today.