# Group ID Filter in Block?

Tags: 7, nodes, views, organic-groups

I want to show teasers of content posted to an OG group.  I want public and private groups, so the user must have view access to that group to see the content. I have a Group (named "Group") and a content type ("Topic") that users can post to the group.

I create a block in views and place it bellow content, then when the group is displayed the block is displayed.  Currently the block will show ALL content, I do not know how to show content for CURRENT GID. The GID is different then the NID (example nid = 3, gid = 1).

- I installed Pathauto and gave the rule to group/[node:nid].
- I then created a block and want the block to show all Group Content.  I set it only to display on group and group/* This is associated with [og_members block & og_nodes block won't display content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/988/og-members-block-og-nodes-block-wont-display-content) but unfortunately the individual did not mention his views filter (or contextual filter).
- I can get all content to show up in this block, but I do not know how to filter the current nodes group id from the block.

Answer (score 2):

Updating views to views 3 Beta 3 created 2 new OG views, OG Nodes was one of them and it fixed the issue.

Note:  Adding blocks to "Content" would ignore weight (order) of the blocks, I had to create a content-top and content-bottom area in page.tpl.php!